# QB IDS V3 Connection Error: AuthentificationErrorGeneral: Interal Server Error , statusCode:500

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Can someone help on this error that i sometime get while connecting to Quickbooks online with IDS V3?

```
Error code:100, ERROR MESSAGE: General AUthentification Error, ERROR DETAIL: AuthentificationErrorGeneral: Interal Server Error , statusCode:500
```

I'm using Java SDK to retrieve data. everything is working great. I don't know why but this error  some time happens.
is anyone faced the same issue.
Thank you

Comment: You get this error generally when service is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error generally when service is down. Yesterday there were some issues. You cna check the status here-
http://developer-status.intuit.com/